# How to store correct value of Date and Time in Mysql database using Spring boot?

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

While connecting spring boot application to MYSQL database, I got this error:

> com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The
>   server time zone value 'unknown' is unrecognized or represents more
>   than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC
>   driver (via the serverTimezone configuration property) to use a more
>   specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

If I use serverTimeZone UTC with data source url, then database value sets to 5:30 times back from current local time and also date will be stored as yesterday's date.

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db?serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false
```

What should I do to set correct value for date and time?

Answer (score 0):

`?serverTimezone=UTC&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false` will work for timezone. I had lots of problems becuase of this little trick even couldnt connect to mysql